# Will Natty Narwhall include Linux 2.6.38?

Tags: kernel, 11.04

Today Linus Torvalds announced the 2.6.38 RC1 Linux Kernel. I know that maybe this kernel will be ready near the date for Natty release and in that case it's inclusion could affect Ubuntu's stability and performance, but looking at [this repo](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/) I found that there is a repo for Natty..

According to the announcement, the improvement for this kernel are really important, in some cases 30% better performance, so my question is if Natty will include this Linux Kernel's version or not? Just I don't know and I wanted to ask.

Regards my friends!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Natty is now using to 2.6.38.

According to the kernel team's [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/Specs/KernelNattyVersionAndFlavours):

> As
>   Natty is not an LTS we do not require
>   a specific version for alignment
>   upstream. Therefore we will be using
>   the latest version released at kernel
>   freeze.

Comment: 2.6.38 is due by the beginning of April so this should be fine.